# How can I get the correct user in a mail filter in CVS loginfo?

Tags: cvs, loginfo

I have a single CVS user (`cvs`) on my Unix box and I map all CVS users to this user via `CVSROOT/passwd`. When I do this, all mails are sent by the user `cvs`. I'd like to show the name of the committer in the mail subject (or even as the sender of the mail).

Is there any other way than creating a real Unix user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CVS will put the commit user name into the variable `$USER` which you can use in the file `loginfo` to call your mail filter.